# Can I set different ordering in WooCommerce Shop page and product based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I applied filter to shop page to display product order by title. But my product in individually category also got affected. My goal is to display product order by title in shop page and display product in individual category by custom sorting+title. May I know is it possible. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes totally possible just add an if statement to your filter, something like:

If( ! Is_product_category() ) {

}